# Parse a XML string into a XML

Tags: java, xml, string

anyone knows how to parse a XML string into a XML?.
I have a String that is, in fact, a XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.huawei.com/schema/syncorder/v1-0/" xmlns:tns="http://www.huawei.com.cn/schema/common/v2_1"><SOAP-ENV:Header><tns:NotifySOAPHeader><tns:spId>35000001</tns:spId><tns:serviceId>35000001000001</tns:serviceId><tns:spRevId/><tns:spRevpassword/></tns:NotifySOAPHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:SyncOrderRelationExt><ns1:userID><ns1:UserID><ns1:ID>12346579801234567890</ns1:ID><ns1:type>0</ns1:type></ns1:UserID></ns1:userID><ns1:SPID>35000001</ns1:SPID><ns1:productID>11111111111</ns1:productID><ns1:serviceID>35000001000001</ns1:serviceID><ns1:serviceList>44444444</ns1:serviceLis<ns1:updateType>1</ns1:updateType><ns1:updateTime>55555555555555</ns1:updateTime><ns1:updateDesc>222222</ns1:updateDesc><ns1:effectiveTime>1256192581666</ns1:effectiveTime><ns1:expiryTime>5555555</ns1:expiryTime><ns1:extensionInfo><ns1:NamedParameterList><ns1:NamedParameters><ns1:ArrayOfNameParameter><ns1:NamedParameter><ns1:key>notifyAddress</ns1:key><ns1:value>http://10.40.63.16:9999/syn</ns1:value></ns1:NamedParameter></ns1:ArrayOfNameParameter></ns1:NamedParameters></ns1:NamedParameterList></ns1:extensionInfo><ns1:notifyAddress/></ns1:SyncOrderRelationExt></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to convert that  string into a XML file, I don´t want to create a file and save it on my computer just form an XML and parse it, because it is easier parse a XML than the String.

Comment: you want to remove NS prefix? `SOAP-ENV:`??

Comment: can you elaborate more on what "a XML" is? Also, it's not possible to desire a new XML file without creating a new file!

Comment: There are tens of threads on this exact subject ... you show zero research effort ..

Comment: You want to write an String of XML in a file, because you think parsing an XML file is easier than parsing an XML-String? That's just wrong.

Comment: @Nishant I don't care about the prefixes, I have to get some of the data inside the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [SAAJ API](http://java.boot.by/wsd-guide/ch05s04.html) or DOM SAX will do that too.

Answer (score 0):

use a Library for that. For instance [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) one

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(yourXmlString);
```